# Keep g++ as default compiler but also export the clang command, in order to add include directory to path

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, clangd

I want to use `clangd` as my linter, `g++` as my compiler and `CMake` as my build system. My project has the following structure:

```
MyProject
├── build
│   ├── ...
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── compile_commands.json -> build/compile_commands.json
├── include
│   └── sorting
│       └── Sorting.h
├── main.cpp
└── src
    └── sorting
        └── Sorting.cpp
```

It is a good practice to separate header and implementation files, which is why I have the `include` and `src` directories. It's also a good practice to add the `include` directory to path. This way, I can do `#include "Sorting.h"`, regardless of the specific hierarchy.
So far I have produced the following CMake code to achieve this:

```
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)

project(DSA
  DESCRIPTION "My DSA Implementations"
  LANGUAGES CXX)


add_library(sorting STATIC src/sorting/Sorting.cpp include/sorting/Sorting.h)
target_include_directories(sorting PUBLIC include)

add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main PUBLIC sorting)
```

However, this only exports the `c++` command to `compile-commands.json` and my `clangd` linter remains broken. Is there a way to achieve what I want? The simplest solution I can think of, is to create another CMake build, where the compiler is set to `clang++`.

By the way, I have a `.clang-tidy` setup file, which I generated using `clang-tidy -checks=bugprone-\*,modernize-\*,performance-\*,readability-\*,cppcoreguidelines-\* --dump-config > .clang-tidy`. Could this be the source of my troubles?

Comment: `target_include_directories(sorting PUBLIC include)` is wrong. You need the full relative path from the CMakeLists.txt for the include folder. It should be `target_include_directories(sorting PUBLIC include/sorting)` if you want to use `#include "Sorting.h"`

Comment: Indeed, replacing `target_include_directories(sorting PUBLIC include)` with `target_include_directories(sorting PUBLIC include/sorting)` fixed the problem. The project now compiles and the linter works properly. Thank you for pointing this out. Are there any other improvements I could possibly make? For example, a "better", more accepted project structure or a "better" way of structuring the CMake file.

Comment: Also, my question is getting downvoted. Obviously, I could improve it further as well. I am open to suggestions to fix it.

Comment: My guess for the downvote was someone thought the problem was a trivial typo that probably won't help future readers.

Comment: I believe this is a reasonable structure for your CMakeLists.txt. With that said I usually only create a single target in each CMakeLists.txt and I have a hierarchy where libraries and executables (main plus supporting utility executables) are in different folders in the tree.

Comment: So, if I understood correctly, you have a CMakeLists.txt file for every directory and you bring them together in the CMakeLists.txt, located in the root folder, using `add_subdirectory()`? I saw this several times already, but I haven't mastered it yet. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Yes most folders (even part of the tree) will have a CMakeLists.txt. One folder that will not is an `include` directory. This is all user preference however I am going by experience from the 16 years I have used CMake at work and home.

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks for all the feedback. I provided some answer in order to mark the question "solved". You could provide your own answer, if you'd like. I will mark it as accepted and upvote it, because it was you, who pointed out my mistake and these extra tips.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for my failure was an improper inclusion of the `include` folder. The correct usage is as follows:

```
target_include_directories(sorting PUBLIC include)
```

```cpp
#include "sorting/Sorting.h" // in main.cpp
```

or,

```
target_include_directories(sorting PUBLIC include/sorting)
```

```cpp
#include "Sorting.h" // in main.cpp
```

Thanks to @drescherjm for pointing out my mistake and providing additional tips in the comments.